# Twitter Fabric integration in android get Response 215

Tags: android, twitter, appfabric

Hey guys i have implemented twitter sharing in my app and got some problem it gave 215 in response

> ```
>   TwitterCore.getInstance().logInGuest(new Callback<AppSession>() {
>             @Override
>             public void success(Result<AppSession> result) {
>                 guestAppSession = result.data;
>                 try {
>                     Log.d("guestAppSession" + guestAppSession.getAuthToken(),
>                             "=" + result.data.getId());
>                 } catch (Exception e) {
>                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                 }
>                 try {
>                     Log.d("URL", "=" + url);
>                     DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
>                     HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
>                     HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
>                     inputStream = res.getEntity().getContent();
>                     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
>                     Log.d("bufferedReader_", "=" + bufferedReader.readLine());
>                     while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null)
>                     {
>                         Log.d("bufferedReader", "=" + bufferedReader.readLine());
>                     }
>                     } catch (Exception e) {
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                 }
>             }
>             @Override
>             public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
>                 // unable to get an AppSession with guest auth
>             }
>         });
> ```
>
> above is my code let me know what is wrong. and give me proper response to implement it...
>   Thanks ..

Error code: {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem as ..

```
TwitterCore.getInstance().logInGuest(
                        new Callback<AppSession>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(
                                    Result<AppSession> appSessionResult) {
                                AppSession guestAppSession = appSessionResult.data;

                                final TwitterApiList apiClient = new TwitterApiList(
                                        guestAppSession);
                                apiClient.getListService().statuses(
                                        " shjh", "user",
                                        50, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void success(
                                                    Result<List<Tweet>> listResult) {
                                                Log.d("twittercommunity",
                                                        "user's profile url is "
                                                                + listResult.data
                                                                        .get(0).user.profileBackgroundColor);
                                                // Do something with the
                                                // list


                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void failure(
                                                    TwitterException e) {
                                                // FAIL

                                            }
                                        });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
```